# How do i send data from 2 inputs into one json server object?

Tags: json, reactjs, input

I am trying to create a simple login sistem using react and json server (on localhost port).
I have 2 inputs, one for name the other for password.
My problem is that when i try to submit those inputs, on the server side both name and password appear with the values from the password.

```
class AddAcc extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.input = null;
    this.pushAcc = this.pushAcc.bind(this)
  }

  async pushAcc() {
    try {
      await Axios
        .post(
          `${BASE_URL}users`,
          {
            name: this.input.value,
            password: this.input.value,
          },
          {
            'Content-Type': 'aplication/json'
          }
        )
      this.props.newAcc(this.input.value);
    } catch(e) {
    }
  }
render() {
  return(
    <div>
      <p>
        <input
          ref={name => this.input = name} />
      </p>
      <div>
        <h3>Enter Password</h3>
      </div>
      <p>
        <input
          ref={pass => this.input = pass} />
      </p>
      <button onClick = {this.pushAcc} type="submit"> SUBMIT </button>
    </div>
  )
}
}

export default AddAcc;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are using same ref  `this.input` for both name and password.

Change for password

```
<input ref={pass => this.passwordInput = pass} />
```

Comment: It's my pleasure

Answer (score 0):

This is simply because you are using same name for name ans pass. So simple solution is this,

```
<input ref={name => this.inputName = name} />
<input ref={pass => this.inputPass = pass} />
```

Then do this,

```
await Axios
    .post(
      `${BASE_URL}users`,
      {
        name: this.inputName.value,
        password: this.inputPass.value,
      },
      {
        'Content-Type': 'aplication/json'
      }
    )
```